# Can i use Styled Media Receiver for display the Slide show image

Tags: ios, iphone, chromecast, google-cast

My App fetches all the media from the Facebook and Instagram and display it on the HDMI TV.

My Problem is Styled Media Receiver allows to display the slide show image one by one.Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

No, Styled Receiver/Default Receiver do not provide any functionality for showing a slide show.